# WordPress.org how to force expire Cached Banner-772x250 from my Plugin page

Tags: plugin-development, svn, plugin-repository

I created and added a banner to my plugin page http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dbc-backup-2/  but there was a spelling mistake so I deleted & committed a new verison.

After I added the new image back in the SVN - it's still showing the old one. So I know that the CDN has cached the image for a very long time. I checked via anonymouse.org just now and the correct banner is showing.

**EDIT** 
It's been three days so far since I uploaded the image and for me I'm still seeing the same broken banner. I guess the CDN is serving out the old cached image to my IP :(

So my questions ...

- is there a way for *developers* to expire the old image? or force it from the cache?
- does anyone know how long these banner images are cached for?

and ...

- Let me know if you are not seeing this image as I've got an update ready but not going to change /trunk until the correct banner is showing for everyone.

([image]

Comment: I couldn't see any difference between this image and the one you're uploaded for your plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was discussed on the [WP Hackers mailing list](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2012-August/043952.html).

> On Tue, Jul 31, 2012 at 7:15 PM, Dion Hulse (dd32)  wrote:
>
> > s-plugins.wordpress.org is a Externally hosted CDN - Edgecast to be specific.
> >
> > Right now, the only way is to wait for it to update, the Edgecast CDN
> >     has a long cache expiry time, so WordPress.org needs to be updated to
> >     add a Cache busting version/revision parameter by the look of it.
>
> The cache-busting parameter has been implemented now. It will take
>   effect on the next plugin update.
>
> So touch the plugin's readme.txt file or perform some other update of
>   your choice, and the cache will get busted for your banner image. It
>   will then get busted again when you change something in the assets
>   directory going forward.
>
> -Otto

Answer (score 0):

In answer to part of my question the banner-772x250 is cached for 7 days on WordPress.org

Though I Never actually managed to force it to clear the cached image

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried changing the image source to something like - `image.jpg?123` We used to do this to update css or image files from cache.

**NOTE** - This is useful trick to force browser / CDN to load updated image instead of old - cached one.

Comment: Unfortunately its not 'my' CDN ... and the banner image has right click protection. The question is for WordPress plugin repo management and how to help me and other plugin developers clear the cached image

Comment: that is not right click protection, they used the image as background instead direct embed.

Comment: after going to the CDN image url and adding ?123 to it i can download the new image but thats not updating the webpage

Comment: what changes you did in the image, coz i'm seeing same image as you mentioned here in SE

Comment: the incorrect one im seeing says 'just 3 key features' so its the cache sending the wrong image to my IP i think

Comment: have you tried clearing your browser cache, coz I'm seeing right image.